# Anyone know of a simple dendrogram visualizer?

Tags: data-visualization, dendrogram

I've written a small hierarchical clustering algorithm (for better or for worse). I'd like a quick way of visualizing it, any tooling ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[TreeView](http://taxonomy.zoology.gla.ac.uk/rod/treeview.html) -- it is not a statistical tool, but it is very light and I have a great sentiment to it; and it is easy to make output to [Newick format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newick_format), which TV eats without problems.

More powerful solution is to use R, but here you would have to invest some time in making conversion to the `dendrogram` object (basically list-of-lists).

Comment: Unfortunately TreeView has given me a wonderful buffer overflow error :(.

Comment: @Hans Strange; unless you're trying to plot something huge, it should have worked. Are you sure the format is OK?

Comment: Perhaps not. My example.tre file: (A,B,(C,D));

Comment: @Hans All I can say is that it works for me :-(

Answer (score 2):

You can use PhyFi web server for generating dendrograms from Newick files. 
Sample output using your data from PhyFi:

[image: PhyFi figure]

Answer (score 2):

[Archaeopteryx](http://www.phylosoft.org/archaeopteryx/) is a Java application that you can use standalone or embed in an application.  [Dendroscope](http://ab.inf.uni-tuebingen.de/software/dendroscope/) is also pretty good.  Both can read files in [Newick format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newick_format), and provide many ways of manipulating the display.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not a tool per-se, ascii art is a fairly safe option actually, and not as hard as it seems at first. It's not pretty, but it gets the point accross.

Comment: ahahahahahahahah